# Any way to set up IntelliJ IDEA to honor OSGi exports/imports for dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, osgi

IntelliJ IDEA 11/12 user, here.

We have a Maven/OSGi multi-module project set up in which `module1` depends on `module2`.  module2 exports packages with `MANIFEST` only.

When coding in `module1`, is there any way to set up IntelliJ IDEA so it honors the exported packages of `module2` and flag any disallowed imports in `module1` as errors (the way Eclipse does this)?

Comment: Probably not, IntelliJ's support for OSGi is non-existent. You might want to vote here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100812. Or just use Bndtools ;-)

Comment: Hey @NeilBartlett. It'd be great if there were an article/blog entry that would decribe how to use bndtools with IntelliJ IDEA. Is there one you'd recommend (or shall I poke about for one)? It'd be even more awesome if we could point at it here, at SO.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Bndtools requires Eclipse. As I said, IntelliJ support for OSGi is non-existent. Anyway, here is the Bndtools tutorial: http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html

Comment: I believe one could create a quite viable OSGi-aware environment in IntelliJ based on Maven where Maven drives dependencies that are set up with appropriate plugins. Don't you think it could work for any IDE, IDEA including? Just thinking aloud.

Comment: I think once you used bndtools you see that you need a bit more than maven. However, bnd, the foundation of bndtools is designed to run in other IDEs, it has no dependency on Eclipse. Just looking for someone to integrate it in IDEA as Neil did for Eclipse

Comment: IntelliJ does actually have quite a lot of support for OSGi, so @NeilBartlett seems to be spreading FUD at this point. While it might be true that bndtools offers more support, it's wrong to slag off an IDE on that basis.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I'm happy to be proven wrong. Link to a document or blog post about it please. My information is based on reports from IntelliJ users who have switched to Bndtools because of the lack of OSGi support in IntelliJ.

Comment: Here's the Jetbrains page describing their OSGi support, as per Neil's quite reasonable request. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/osgi.html

Comment: I might switch too, if it had better support, but that doesn't mean that it's support is 'non-existant'. You really are encouraged to try it yourself too, as it's open-source and free (although in the free version, you have to use the plug-in version of the support, as it's only fully integrated in the commercial version -- and there's nothing wrong with people making some money).

Comment: I say quite reasonable -- quite reasonable would have been to google it. This is the opposite of reasonable really, but I don't actually mind -- I'm here to help :-p